# Finding Random variables measurable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If $[0,1]$ is our sample space and our sigma algebra is generated by all segments of the form $[0,2^{-n}]$. How can we describe the random variables measurable with respect to our sigma algebra? I'm thinking I can do this with an indicator function, but not sure. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$$X=x\,\mathbf 1_{\{0\}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\,\mathbf 1_{(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]}$$